# Sorting through request.GET in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I want people to be able to sort things and not just me sorting things manually. So, for example, I will have a link to sorting, and the link will be something like, `/?sort=issues` and this would show a list of issues in alphabetical order, etc. Or `/?sort=cover` and it will show a list of issues with covers only.

Views.py

```
def issues(request):
    issues_list = Issue.objects.order_by('-date_added')
    paginator = Paginator(issues_list, 24)
    try:
        page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
    except ValueError:
        page = 1
    try:
        issues = paginator.page(page)
    except (EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
        issues = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render_to_response('comics/issues.html', {'issues': issues}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

So, I'd want anyone to have the option of ordering by something like `-date_added`, `date_addded`, `pub_date`, `importance`, etc.

I'd imagine I'd have to fix my views and do some request.GET magic, but I am pretty new to Django and don't really know how to go about doing this. I checked Django docs, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sort_by = request.GET.get('sort', '-date_added')
if sort_by not in ['-date_added', 'date_addded', 'pub_date', 'importance']:
     sort_by = '-date_added'
issues_list = Issue.objects.order_by(sort_by)
```

Comment: I can't believe how simple this is. Thank you! What about the pagination though? If I sort by `pub_date` and click on the next page, it goes back to the default ordering.

Comment: @Aimee That's why you should add `?sort=...` to your links in template. Or use some existing solutions like [django-sorting](https://github.com/agiliq/django-sorting).

Comment: I did add `?sort=...` to my template as links. Adding `/?sort=pub_date/?page=2` isn't working either... I'd rather not add a new application for something like this.

Comment: @Aimee Yes, you will need to encode url manually. Copy `request.GET`, alter it as you like, and then use its `urlencode` method. It's a good tutrial, but if you want working solution I recommend to use one of existing apps.

Comment: What I'm saying is that `/?sort=pub_date` works but adding `/?page=2` to the end of it just switches it back to the default. How would I change that?

Comment: @Aimee `/?sort=pub_date&page=2`

Comment: What do you mean by copying `request.GET` and using `urlencode`? I've checked the docs....no help there.

Comment: @Aimee https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.urlencode

Answer (score 0):

Put it at the top of your view:

```
user_specified = request.GET.get('sort', **''**)

if user_specified:
  issues_list = Issue.objects.order_by(user_specified)
else: # default ordering
  issues_list = Issue.objects.order_by('-date_added')
```

NB: Haven't tested this!